# Is there a least squares estimator for correlated, non-constant variance errors?

Tags: statistics, regression, least-squares, weighted-least-squares

For OLS we have $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$,

For non-constant variance we have $\hat{\beta} = (X^TWX)^{-1}X^TWy$,

but what if we have, for example $Y = X\beta + \epsilon $ where $\epsilon \sim N(0, aK +bI_{n})$ where k is a covariance matrix and $a,b$ are positive constants?

I tried spectral decomposing K to simplify a bit,

$aK + bI_{n} = U(\frac{a}{a+b}Λ + (1 − \frac{a}{a+b})I)U^{T}$

but now I'm unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just denote $ W = aK + bI$, then 
$$
W ^{-1} = (aK + bI )^{-1} = (aP\Lambda P^T + bP P^T)^{-1}=(P(a\Lambda+bI)P ^ T)^{-1}
 = P (a\Lambda+bI)^{-1}P^T,
$$
hence, 
$$
W ^{ -1/2} = P(a\Lambda + bI )^{-1/2}P^T.
$$
Namely, the transformation of the WLS is 
$$
W ^{-1/2}Y = P(a\Lambda+ bI)^{-1/2}P^T Y.
$$
Verification
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(W ^{-1/2}Y) &= W ^{-1/2} (aK + bI) W^{-1/2}\\
                               &= P(a\Lambda + bI )^{-1/2}P^T P(a\Lambda + bI )P^T P(a\Lambda + bI )^{-1/2}P^T \\
                               &= PP^T\\
&=I. 
\end{align}

So, 
$$
\hat{\beta} = (X'W^{-1}X)^{-1}X'W^{-1}y
$$
is the WLS.

Answer (score 0):

It should be identical to your second case (edit: which is incorrect as you have written, see the other answer for the correct $\hat \beta$). Let $W = aK+bI$.

This is generalized least squares (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares).